# Where can I find model.ckpt in faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco model?

Tags: tensorflow

In an awesome tutorial about [using the tensorflow API for transfer learning](https://medium.com/@WuStangDan/step-by-step-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial-part-4-training-the-model-68a9e5d5a333), I found the following instructions:

- Copy the config file for the model you selected and move it to a new folder where you will perform all the training
- change the fine_tune_checkpoint path to point to the model.ckpt file

Since I want to use resnet, I downloaded the faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco model from  [tensorflows model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)  and unpacked it, but instead of a "model.ckpt" I only found the following three files with a ckpt ending:

- model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.meta

So where can I find the model.ckpt file mentioned in the tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out myself, that there is actually no contradiction. All three files with .ckpt. are needed and the configuration file mentioned in the tutorial has to point to

```
[DirectoryContainingTheCkptFiles]/model.ckpt.
```

I.e., there is no model.ckpt file. It is just an entry marker for the train.py script, to find the three .ckpt. files during training.