# Unable to load pre-trained model checkpoint with TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-segmentation, object-detection-api

Similar to this question:

[Where can I find model.ckpt in faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507040/where-can-i-find-model-ckpt-in-faster-rcnn-resnet50-coco-model) (this solution doesn't work for me)

I have downloaded the `ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8` with the intention of using it as a starting point. I am using the sample model configuration associated with that model in the TF model zoo.

I am only changing the num classes and paths for tuning, training and eval.

With:

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:\\Users\\Peter\\Desktop\\Adv-ML-Project\\models\\research\\object_detection\\test_data\\checkpoint\\model.ckpt"
```

I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for C:\Users\Pierre\Desktop\Adv-ML-Project\models\research\object_detection\test_data\checkpoint\model.ckpt
```

With:

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:\\Users\\Peter\\Desktop\\Adv-ML-Project\\models\\research\\object_detection\\test_data\\checkpoint\\ckpt-0.*"
```

I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file C:\Users\Pierre\Desktop\Adv-ML-Project\models\research\object_detection\test_data\checkpoint\ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad mag
ic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

I'm currently using absolute paths because it's easiest, but if it's a problem I can re-organize my project structure.

[Checkpoint Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQr81.png)

The official documentation from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_training_and_evaluation.md
says to do something like

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: a path prefix to the pre-existing checkpoint (ie:"/usr/home/username/checkpoint/model.ckpt-#####").
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here? I am running this with the following command (also from documentation):

```
python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path="C:\\Users\Pierre\\Desktop\\Adv-ML-Project\\models\\my_model\\my_model.config" \
    --model_dir="C:\\Users\\Pierre\\Desktop\\Adv-ML-Project\\models\\my_model\\training" \
    --alsologtostderr
```

Comment: Where did you download the model checkpoint and config for `ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8`? I can't seem to find it in the Tensorflow model garden. Could you share the link?

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi here is the model zoo link https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md 

To actually download it, I had to right click + copy link on the one I wanted and then use that with curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `fine_tune_checkpoint` path in the config file to something like `path_to_folder/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0`

And in your training command, set the `model_dir` flag to just point to the model directory, don't include `training`, kind of like `--model_dir=<path_to>/ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8`

[Source](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#configure-the-training-pipeline)

Just change the backslashes to forward-slashes, since you're on windows

Comment: Hi, this worked thanks so much, I can't believe out of everything I tried I wasn't able to get this to work.